# Generalized inverse of orthogonal perpendicular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

Assume that an orthogonal projection matrix is given as $$ A = \left[ X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^-X'\Sigma^{-1}\right]$$
where $\Sigma$ is positive definite and $X_{m\times n}$ is design matrix. Show that $A$ is the same for any choice of $(X' \Sigma^{-1} X)^-.$

My Idea: Let $G = (X' \Sigma X)^-$ be a generalized inverse of $A$ and since $G$ is not unique, we assume $G_\star$ to be another generalized inverse of $A$ such that $$AG_\star A = A$$ so that we could have
\begin{align} 
[A]G_\star [A] & =  \left[ X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^-X' \Sigma^{-1} \right] (X' \Sigma^{-1} X)_\star^-  \left[ X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^-X\Sigma^{-1} \right] \\
& =  \left[ X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^-X' \Sigma^{-1} \right]  X^{'-}_\star \Sigma _\star X_\star^-  \cdot \left[ X X'^- \Sigma X ^-X\Sigma^{-1} \right] \\
&   = \left[ X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^-X' \Sigma^{-1} \right] \left[(X_\star'^-X')\cdot (\Sigma_\star\Sigma^{-1})  \cdot(X_\star^-X) \cdot (X^- X) \cdot \Sigma \right]\\
& = \left[ X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^-X' \Sigma^{-1} \right] \left[I \cdot I \cdot I \cdot I \cdot \Sigma \right]\\
& = \left[ X(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^-X' \Sigma^{-1} \right] \Sigma\\
& \neq A
\end{align}

I probably did something incorrect. What am I missing?